# How to include loan rules in Employee and Loan sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables `Employee`, `Loan` and `LoanInstallment`.

`Employee` table has one to many relation with `Loan`, and `Loan` has one to 
many with `LoanInstallment`.

- `Employee` (EmpId, Name, IsOnProbation)
- `Loan` (LoanId, EmpId, StartDate, EndDate).

Now I need to write a query to fetch the records of employee in following output.

Output records (EmpId, Name, Status, Reason)

Rules

- if employee has not taken loan never then its status should be Eligible and reason as loan not taken.
- if employee has taken loan within one year (i.e EndDate is less than one year) then its status should be Not Eligible and reason loan already taken.
- if employee is on probation then status should be Not Eligible and Reason on Probation
- if employee has taken laon 1 year ago then status should be Eligible and Reason Loan taken 1 year ago.

I have written a simple query but I am unable to understand how to include all the four rules and include Reason column in this single query.

```
SELECT
    e.EmployeeID, E.FullName,l.EndDate, 
    (CASE
        WHEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, max(l.EndDate), GETDATE()) < 0  
           THEN 'Eligible'
           ELSE 'Not Eligible'
     END) as Status
FROM 
    Employee e 
LEFT JOIN
    Loan l ON e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID
GROUP BY
    e.EmployeeID, e.FullName, l.EndDate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the rest of the conditions to your case statement.
As for the Reason column, your case statement will be pretty much the same but instead of the status you need to set the reason.
Also, `case when DATEDIFF(YEAR, max(l.EndDate), GETDATE()) < 0` is wrong as the result can never be less than 0.

This should do it:

```
select e.EmployeeID, E.FullName,l.EndDate, 
       (case when l.EmployeeID is null then 'Eligible'
             when DATEDIFF(month, max(l.EndDate), GETDATE()) > 12  then 'Eligible' 
             when DATEDIFF(month, max(l.EndDate), GETDATE()) =<  12  then 'Not Eligible' 
             when l.IsOnProbation = 1 then 'Not Eligible' 
        else 'Not Eligible'
        end) as Status,
         (case when l.EmployeeID is null then 'Loan not taken'
             when DATEDIFF(month, max(l.EndDate), GETDATE()) > 12  then 'Loan taken over 1 year ago' 
             when DATEDIFF(month, max(l.EndDate), GETDATE()) <=  12  then 'Loan already taken' 
             when l.IsOnProbation = 1 then 'On probation' 
        else 'Not Eligible'
        end) as Reason
FROM Employee e 
    left join Loan l on e.EmployeeID = l.EmployeeID
group by e.EmployeeID, e.FullName, l.EndDate
```